# Is it possible to use something returns from python on Node JS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I need to use JS and also i have a python script that i have to use. With print statement JavaScript can use the python output but my python function returns list and integer so print format not useful for this case. For example i wrote a python script which contains function. But this JS code work with print function.

Python Code

```py
import sys
def function(a,b):
    variable = a+b
    return variable

function(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

JS Code

```js
const express = require('express')
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const app = express()
const port = 3000
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 
 var dataToSend;
 // spawn new child process to call the python script
 const python = spawn('python', ['script2.py','num' ,'python']);
 // collect data from script
 python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('Pipe data from python script ...');
  dataToSend = data.toString();
  console.log(dataToSend)
 });
 // in close event we are sure that stream from child process is closed
 python.on('close', (code) => {
 // send data to browser
 res.send(dataToSend)
 });
 
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 
${port}!`))
```

Is there a way that use the python function returns use on JS as arg1,arg2,arg3

Comment: Can you do something like json.dumps(myPythonObject) in python before returning, and then JSON.parse(myPythonJsonDump) in JS when you receive it?